# How to override a class within an Android library project?

Tags: android, class, project, android-library

The following is my situation:

I have a library project and a project based on it.  Now in the library I have two classes A and B, whereby A uses B. In the project using the library, I have another class B, which should override the class B from the library.

But every time class A makes a call, it ends up in the class B from the library.
How can I tell Android that class B from my project should be used INSTEAD of class B from the library?

Comment: Are both B in the library and yours reside in the same package?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. A and B are both in the library, since A will be shared by other projects and A needs B. Class B is implemented differently for each project, so each project should use it's own Class B (together with class A from the library).

Comment: OK, I'll answer your question, according this new information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That does not work with the current layout. You have to use the strategy pattern. In your library define LibA with a constructor that takes a object of type LibB in the constructor:

```
class LibA{
    LibB b;
    public LibA(LibB b)
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Then you can override LibB in your project and create LibA with the class that extends LibB:

```
class ProjectB extends LibB{

}

LibA a = new LibA(new ProjectB());
```

---

Answer to Turbos question:

You want to start Project-Activities from your Library. So then **move the code that creates the `Intent` into your Projects**, because only in your project you know the type or name of the `Activity` to be started.

The solution you mentioned in your comment ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951610/best-practice-extending-or-overriding-an-android-library-project-class)) creates the `Intent` in the library project, by guessing the name of the `Activity` that should be started. There is nothing really wrong with that but it's not an elegant solution. You can only start `Activities` that follow that special naming scheme. And because of that you cannot start arbitrary `Activities` that are visible in your projects like `Activities` from other libraries, where you cannot change the name of the class.

To move the `Intent` creation into your libraries you can i.e. use the strategy, template or factory-method pattern. See [Design Patterns on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Creational_patterns) for even more (creational) patterns that match your library design.

A simple solution would be:

Create an abstract `LibraryActivity` and extend your ProjectActivities from it. The `LibraryActivity` defines an abstract method that returns the `Intent`. The implementation of that abstract method is done in your `ProjectActivities`.

```
abstract class LibActivity{

    private void doSomething(){
        //Library does something

        //and finally calls createIntent() to start an project specific Activity
        startActivity(this.createIntent());
    }

    protected abstract Intent createIntent();
}


class ProjectActivity extends LibActivity{

    protected Intent createIntent(){
        return new Intent(ProjectActivity.this, AnyActivityYouWant.class);
    }        
}
```

Comment: How can this be adapted for Android `Activity` classes since there are no constructors for those classes?

Comment: @Turbo I added an example for situations where you cannot use custom constructors.

Comment: thanks for the additional answer. For clarification, this means that if LibActivity is not a root activity (i.e. it is actually launched from another activity, say MainActivity) then we would have to continue up the chain with the overriding and factory method? I ask because sometimes the activity that needs to be modified is a few screens/activities away.

Comment: I think I don't really understand your question. LibActivity (in my example) cannot be instantiated - it's abstract. The code here shows how a library can be implemented that allows customizing certain tasks when using the library.

Comment: apologies, I missed that keyword. My question is, say you have 2 projects that each need to return their own LibB modified class. They would each have activities that extend `LibActivity`, but then if there is core library project code that launches a `LibActivity` through an intent, you need to provide a name of that class in the Intent. And there are two names since we have 2 project applications. I ended up using the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951610/best-practice-extending-or-overriding-an-android-library-project-class Though I wonder if yours would work.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is the best way to do it but i do it this way;

I create a class A from the project and this class extends form the library project

```
public class A extends libraryProject_A{

//here i put all methods from the new class B to override methods from library class B

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your comment you have class A that uses class B

But class B should be different according to which project you're using.

I think you need to create a base class say BaseB that will be an instance variable in class A, and you might have a setter and getter for this Or you can make it a parameter passed to the constructor of class A. and when instantiating A you should choose which one to use.

Let's have a look at code

```
Class A {
 private BaseB b;
 public A(BaseB aB) {
   b = aB;
 }

 public void set(BaseB aB) {
  b = aB;
 }
 public BaseB get() {
   return b;
 }
}

interface BaseB {
}


// in the library have this
class B implements BaseB {
}

// in your project have the other implementation
class B implements BaseB {
}

// you can then instantiate A like this
A a = new A(new B());
// you can choose which one to use here in the previous statement.
```