# How to override an activity in Android library jar file?

Tags: android, jar

I have added a JAR library file to my Android application for payment system. I would like to change the code of the one of the java file in JAR library file to make it work as needed. How would i do that in Android studio?

Comment: Do you have the source code of .jar file ?

Comment: Add the code of the class you want to change and show us what you've tried

Comment: You should override the class method you want to change with your own code

Comment: You want to.... modify a (possibly closed source) payment system library? Isn't that kind of insecure and unethical?

Answer (score 0):

In order to overwrite a library's "SampleActivity" class it a the project which depends on that library, create a new class with the name SampleActivityExtended in the project in the same package and add the new activity to your AndroidManifest.xml.

IMPORTANT: all intents referencing overwritten activities should be created through the util class in the following manner:

more detail you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951610/best-practice-extending-or-overriding-an-android-library-project-class)

Comment: Could you given a simpler example?