# Overriding an Android library project asset file

Tags: android, android-library

Based on the following links:

[Best practice: Extending or overriding an Android library project class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9951610/best-practice-extending-or-overriding-an-android-library-project-class)

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html#resource_merging

classes and resources in the Android library (AAR) are override-able. How about overriding an asset file? In my AAR file, I have an asset named `first.xml`. I want to create my own `first.xml` in my android project that overrides the file in my AAR. How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the result of my test.

This is my assets/ inside the AAR:

```
-assets/
 -a.xml
 -b.xml
```

This is my assets/ inside my android project that depends on the AAR above:

```
-assets/
 -b.xml
 -c.xml
```

The resulting assets/ in my APK is below:

```
-assets/
 -a.xml (from AAR)
 -b.xml (from my project)
 -c.xml (from my project)
```