# Override library class called by a library in Java

Tags: java, android, overriding, libraries

I call `myConnection.open()` from my MainActivity. `myConnection` is an object of the library class `Connection`:

```
public class Connection implements SomeOtherLibraryClass { ... }
```

providing the function

```
public void open(){ this.mCurrentConnection = this.mConnectionFactory.createConnection(); }
```

which invokes another library class:

```
public class ConnectionFactory { ... }
```

having the constructor

```
public ConnectionFactory(){ mInitCommand = "Original Bla"; }
```

and processing `mInitCommand` in the `createConnection` function.

Now I would like to **override** the content of `mInitCommand` **before being processed** in the `createConnection` function like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6564133/how-to-override-a-class-within-an-android-library-project), **but without touching the library classes**.

---

I know that I could create an object of a new class extending `ConnectionFactory` and overriding the variable, but then I would have to change `mConnectionFactory` to point to my customized class instead of the original one.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: How is `Connection` instantiated? Can you pass a custom factory? Which library is this?

Comment: That's a bit tricky and I did not deeply understand it yet: `onServiceConnected` I have `myConnection = (ServiceType) service` and `service` get's passed as an IBinder object. I got this from the libraries documentation, which is a closed source library of my company.
Unfortunately I don't see how I could pass a custom ConnectionFactory, since the ConnectionFactory gets invoked by the Connection class which I cannot modify.

Comment: We can't really help you use a closed source library unless you're willing to post some of the code or documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately the library is pretty big and I won't be allowed to release it here, therefore I tried to abstract and generalize the question as much as possible. So am I right that there is no trivial way of overriding the last class in a chain and make the other classes use the overridden version without changing them?